# How do I narrow a union of objects with a generic value?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an object of the following type:

```js
type T = {
    a: number;
    b?: never;
} | {
    a?: never;
    b: number;
}

const fn = async (t: T) => {
    if (typeof t.a === "number") {
        const x = t.a; // number
        const y = t.b; // undefined
    } else {
        const x = t.a; // undefined
        const y = t.b; // number
    }
}
```

Here, inside the `if (typeof t.a === "number")` branch, TS correctly infers that `t.a` is `number` and `t.b` is `undefined`.

Now let's say I have the same setup, but instead of `a: number`, it's generic:

```
type T2<Q> = {
    a: Q;
    b?: never;
} | {
    a?: never;
    b: Q;
}


const fn2 = async <Q extends object>(t: T2<Q>) => {
    if (typeof t.a === "object") {
        const x = t.a; // Q extends object 
        const y = t.b; // Q | undefined
    } else {
        const x = t.a; // Q | undefined
        const y = t.b; // Q | undefined
    }
}
```

What's happening here? Why does the type inference no longer work? What conditions do I need to place on `Q`, or what check do I need to run, to make it correctly infer that `t.a` is `Q` and `t.b` is `undefined` (and vice versa) as appropriate?

Comment: You can’t do this; it’s not considered a discriminated union if the intended discriminant is generic. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50652 .  This may or may not be a bug in TS (still listed as “needs investigation”). Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer; if not what am I missing?